# iOS : Music goes off while playing a sound effect

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I am trying to play a short music but when iPod is playing and lunch the application music goes off ! how can I prevent this situation ? I am using `AVAudioPlayer` to play sound .
thanks

Comment: In no way.. This is a default system behaviour.

Comment: Same thing, as far as I know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `AudioToolBox` and and short effect sounds you can use `kAudioSessionCategory`

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, self);
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);  
AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
```

hopes can help ;)